# How to hide an API key when deploying a website to Netlify

Tags: javascript, netlify

So I made a small website with Javascript, just for fun and wanted to deploy it to Netlify. The issue is that the website uses an API key which I'm not sure how to hide. At the moment the key is stored in a variable in the JS file that also contains all the logic of the website.

Just to clarify I'm not tryting to hide the API key from the git repo, but from the JS file after deploying it to Netlify.

Is that even possible on Netlify?

Comment: If the API is to be accessed from client-side code, then the key has to be there when the code gets to a client browser.

Comment: Yes that's the case with this website, because a request is made to the API depending on some user input. So does that mean that I can't hide the API key on Netlify then?

Comment: It's not really a function of how the server works; ultimately, you're delivering HTML and CSS and JavaScript to client web browsers, and web browsers have never heard of Netlify. Generically, accessing API-keyed services is done from a server-side facility to keep access keys private. I have no idea whether Netlify provides proxy service mechanisms like that, but if you ask their customer support people they will know what you're talking about at least.

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy a site into Netlify after that go to -

```
'Site settings' > 'Build & deploy' > 'Environment' > 'Environment variables'
```

You will find a button "**Edit variables**", here you can store your API_KEY Name & its value as key:value pairs.

[Demo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRfAp.png)
[Demo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mc7Q.png)